# How do I split a pathname-like string for use in a Makefile?

Tags: perl, shell, makefile

I have this Makefile code:

```
%.spf:
    @echo $@;
    runMe.sh $1 $2 $3 $4 $5;
```

An example value of the `%.spf` would be:

```
ros_apple/bananas_go_while_197815:123.0/monkey_110_worst_forever/thestar.spf
```

How would I go about extracting the arguments of the filename into variables?

```
$1 = ros_apple
$2 = bananas_go_while_197815:123.0
$3 = worst
$4 = 110
$5 = thestar
```

Is it possible to stay within the Makefile or do I have to create some Perl script that takes in the `$@` and does the shell calling within?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need the path components in a variable or do you just need to offer them to `runMe.sh` split? If the latter, then you can get it done with just `sed` and `tr` (or just `sed`). For example, saying `make all` with this:

```
X=ros_apple/bananas_go_while_197815:123.0/monkey_110_worst_forever/thestar.spf
all:
        @echo `echo $X | sed 's:\.spf$$::' | tr '/' ' '`
```

produces:

```
ros_apple bananas_go_while_197815:123.0 monkey_110_worst_forever thestar
```

So maybe try this:

```
%.spf:
        @echo $@
        runMe.sh `echo $X | sed 's:\.spf$$::' | tr '/' ' '`
```

If you're dead set on doing it in Perl then you can convert the `sed` and `tr` to Perl pretty easily.

Comment: i would just pipe the stuff into perl and call another shell within

Answer (score 1):

However ugly this is, you can probably do nested calls to [dir](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions) for components 1 through 4, and `notdir` for the basename, and possibly use a pattern match to strip off the final slash.