# split a path name for dependecies in a makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to split the path of a variable into a list.
For example, to convert `a/b/c/d` into `a b c d`.
The question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899363/how-do-i-split-a-pathname-like-string-for-use-in-a-makefile), but only a workaround was given, which cannot work with dependencies.

need to split a file name for dependecies.

For example the rule

```
wd/%.o : $1.c $2.c
    cc -o $@ -c $1.c $2.c
```

applied to `wd/a/x.o` would depend on `a.c` and `x.c`.
I managed to create a specialized function that splits the string.  But it works only if we know in advance all the possible values of `$1` and moreover, combining `call` and `%` *does not work*, so I cannot get the result for dependencies.

For example,

```
wd/%.o : $(call SPLIT,%.o) #DO NOT WORK
    cc -o $@ -c $^
```

called on target wd/a/x.o would have only only one dependency, a/x.o, even if SPLIT works fine in the command line.

Any idea ?  Thank you for helping !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [subst](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) function can split the path. To use it in the prerequisite list, use [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
wd/%.o : $$(addsuffix .c,$$(patsubst %,%.c,$$(subst /, ,$$*)))
    cc -o $@ -c $^
```

Comment: That secondary expansion is smart, I did not know that trick.  Thank you.